The right-hand side of an 'instanceof' expression must not be an instantiation expression
I upgraded typescript in my Angular project from 4.9 to 5.2. Now I'm getting this syntax error: The right-hand side of an 'instanceof' expression must not be an instantiation expression.
Here is my problem code:
const oldSelectedItems = this.selectedItems.filter((s) => !(s instanceof GroupableMultiSelect<MultiSelectItem>));

Here this.selectedItems is of type any[]. Now the compiler is unhappy with my generic type GroupableMultiSelect<MultiSelectItem>.
export class GroupableMultiSelect<T extends MultiSelectItem> {
  public groupName: string;
  public item: T;
  public id: number;
  public patientCount: number;
  public name: string;
  public itemRemoved: boolean = false;
  constructor(name: string, item: T) {
    this.item = item;
    this.groupName = name;
    this.name = this.item.name;
    this.id = this.item.id;
    this.patientCount = this.item.patientCount;
  }
}

Can anyone tell me what the problem is here and how to resolve this? Is there a new way to do this in typescript 5.2?

You can't use instantiation expressions that way. Just don't use the type argument (that is, write instanceof GroupableMultiSelect and not instanceof GroupableMultiSelect<XXX>, as shown in this playground link. Before TypeScript 5.1 that wasn't a compiler error but it didn't do what you wanted.  Does this fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

@jcalz Yes I think this answers my question. Thanks!

It wasn't meant to be allowed; just remove the type argument to get rid of the error. That is, write (s instanceof GroupableMultiSelect) instead of (s instanceof GroupableMultiSelect<MultiSelectItem>).

Instantiation expressions were introduced in TypeScript 4.7, and they let you specify a generic function (or constructor)'s type arguments without calling (or newing) it. But nobody thought about what it would mean or seem to mean to allow instantiation expressions in the right hand side of an instanceof expression.
Generics exist only in TypeScript and are erased along with the rest of the type system when TypeScript is compiled to JavaScript. By the time your JavaScript runs, there is no trace of generics.  That means, at runtime, (s instanceof GroupableMultiSelect<MultiSelectItem>) could only ever be (s instanceof GroupableMultiSelect).
By allowing instantiation expressions in the right hand side of an instanceof expression, it looks like you're somehow checking the type argument also, so that (for example) instanceof Array<string> and instanceof Array<number> are checking whether you've got a string[] or number[]. But that's misleading and untrue. All you're checking for is instanceof Array, and in fact, that's how TypeScript actually narrows. You might as well just write instanceof Array in TypeScript also, since the instantiation expression is only possibly there to fool you into thinking you've done something at runtime which is impossible to do.
This was noticed while investigating a similar issue, and was fixed in microsoft/TypeScript#53323 by disallowing such misleading checks.  This feature was released in TypeScript 5.1.  So from TypeScript 4.7 through 5.0, you could write instantiation expressions with instanceof, get no error, but it wouldn't do anything to help you. Starting with TypeScript 5.1, you now get the error that instantiation expressions are forbidden there.  The correct approach is to simply remove the type argument.
Playground link to code
